# Exibir posições em que a letra se repete na palavra

Tags: c, for, codeblocks, mingw, programação-imperativa

Testei esse código que tava na apostila que a professora usou na aula, ele  exibe a primeira posição em que a letra aparece na palavra. Eu quero fazer com que ele identifique que a letra se repete e exiba as posições em que ela se encontra. Como eu poderia fazer isso?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main()
    {
     char S[16], C;

     printf("Digite uma palavra: ");
     scanf("%s",S);
     printf("Digite um caractere: ");
     scanf(" %c",&C);
     int cont, pos=-1;
     for (cont=0; cont<=strlen(S)-1; cont++)
     if (S[cont]==C) 
    {
      pos=cont;
      break;
    }
     if (pos==-1)
      printf("Nao ha ocorrencia de %c em %s.",C,S);
     else
      printf("A 1a ocorrencia de %c em %s eh: %d.",C,S,pos+1);
     return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fazendo de um modo mais básico ficaria dessa forma, você tem que ter em mente que a string é um array, e que array possui índice iniciando em 0, vai até o final da palavra e o último sempre é um "\0" no caso de string em C. Criei um laço for que percorre o array string e compara os caracteres, caso seja igual eu pego o índice no caso o i e imprimo na tela, alem de contar para mostrar quantas vezes o caractere aparece, você poderia até mesmo criar um texto e colocar uma palavra inteira colocando um for dentro do outro e procurar palavras ao invés de caracteres.

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void main(){
    char s[16], c;
    int cont=0;
    printf("Digite uma palavra: ");
    scanf("%s",s);
    printf("Digite um caractere: ");
    scanf(" %c",&c);
    printf("\nAs posicoes em que ela se encontra :");
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(s);i++){
        if(s[i] == c){
            cont++;
            printf("%d ,",i);
        }
    }
    printf("\n A quantidade que o %c aparece eh : %d",c,cont);
}
```